# QML Question about Calling Nested Variables

Tags: qt, variables, nested, qml

So I want to call a variable from an object within an object several levels down. The only way I've figured out how to do it successfully is as follows:

```
//object doing the calling
Text { 
  text: lv1.lv1Out
} 

//object containing the variable I want
Rectangle {
  id: lv1
  property var lv1Out: lv2Out
  
  Rectangle {
    id: lv2
    property var lv2Out: variableIWant
    
    Rectangle {
      id: lv3
      property var variableIWant: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I have to define variables at every level, and define the variable I want all the way out of the containing object tree. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Calling the following doesn't work for me:

```
Text { 
  text: lv1.lv2.lv3.variableIWant;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I think you should just be able to use `text: variableIWant` directly, as long as they are in the same file and there are no other naming conflicts. A more complete example would help.

Comment: what do you want to do by using `lv1.lv2.lv3.variableIWant`? Actually there is no property `lv2` in the item `lv1` so notation `lv1.lv2` makes no sense. Just use `lv3.variableIWant` since `lv3` is not dynamic item and can be accessed directly. See more info in the [Scope and Naming Resolution](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html) doc.

Comment: In case you are talking different qml files, you define an alias on the Rectangle: `property alias nestedVarIWant: lv3.variableIWant` and use that from Text: `text: lv1.nestedVarIWant`

Answer (score 0):

Calling a.b.c for nested definitions will not work because children object are contained in parent object but not as variable/property. For this type of inspection you need to use attribute children[i] - in your case children of children and loop over children.
But in your case it **is is unnecessary**. You have children object named by id so can can do:

```
Text { 
  text: lv3.variableIWant;
}
```